# What does the last sentence below, in bold, has to do with copying a thrown exception?

Tags: c++, exception

This is an excerpt of Stroustup's book, 3rd edition, at page 362 :

> In principle, an exception is copied when it is thrown, so the handler gets hold of a copy of the
>   original exception. In fact, an exception may be copied several times before it is caught. Consequently,
>   we cannot throw an exception that cannot be copied. The implementation may apply a
>   wide variety of strategies for storing and transmitting exceptions. **It is guaranteed, however, that
>   there is sufficient memory to allow new to throw the standard outofmemory
>   exception, bad_alloc.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, when you `throw` an exception, it is a two step process:

1. The exception is locally built on the stack
2. The exception is thrown, which involves making a copy stored "somewhere" and destroying the temporary that was on the stack.

The standard guarantees that in the case there is no longer any memory available to you, the system still has enough memory available to be able to `throw` a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

There are several strategies available:

- simply have the exception statically allocated somewhere, and "fake" throwing it (just passing around a reference to the static one)
- reserve some space (just enough) for the exception
- ...

In general, the runtime puts aside some space to copy exceptions without actually performing a memory allocation. So just re-using this space is fairly common.

Comment: How does the system guarantee this ?

Comment: @user1042389: guarantees what ? (I edited the answer to add some more information so you may have missed the edit).

Comment: Could be more specific about this "fake" throwing ? I didn't understand what you meant by this.

Comment: "simply have the exception statically allocated somewhere" - there's a bit more to it than that, since there can be multiple `bad_alloc` exceptions in existence at once, even in a single-threaded program. If I catch, and in the catch handler I call some code that throws `bad_alloc`, then (before it gets back out of my handler and the first one stops existing) that second one must AFAIK have a different address from the first. A statically-allocated exception per thread can certainly cover most situations, but it's not enough to guarantee that `bad_alloc` is always successfully thrown.

Comment: @SteveJessop So you are basically saying is that what's written in the book is not correct !

Comment: @user1042389: I'm not saying that, I'm just saying that AFAIK to provide that guarantee, you'd have to do more than just have one `bad_alloc` per thread stashed away and ready to go. I think one per `try` block would be adequate, although a little wasteful of stack. I don't know whether the book is correct or not - I don't remember seeing that guarantee explicitly in the standard, but I also don't remember seeing any provision for `throw bad_alloc();` being permitted to fail. So it may be implicitly required that implementations do something that actually isn't realistically do-able.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I wonder if it is special-cased or not. If I were an implementer I guess I would simply aim for a pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 10):

It means that if you run out of memory and a call to new() throws a std::bad_alloc, there will be some memory reserved to create, and make the correct number of copies of the std::bad_alloc object without throwing another std::bad_alloc as a result of the process of throwing the exception.

Comment: How does the compiler guarantees there will always be memory available for copying the `bad_alloc` object ?

Comment: @user1042389: either it fakes copying (elision is allowed after all) or it reserve space at startup that will never be returned to you and keep it aside just for this use.

Comment: The spec itself doesn't say how the compiler is supposed to do it, just that it has obey this behavior. If I were writing a compiler I would likely reserve some memory on the stack somewhere, maybe inside the scope of the try block, or maybe some statically allocated piece of memory.

Answer (score 2):

it means if you enter new and there is not enough memory to allocate anything (ie you're totally out of memory), there will still be a pre-reserved buffer in the system that is big enough to create a 'bad_alloc' exception and throw it.

If you'd run out of memory, how would you expect the system to copy anything? That's why this is important in this section - it says that all exceptions need to be copied, but in the case where there is no memory, you can still get one of these special ones out to tell the rest of your app what's happened.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that `new` will always correctly throw the `bad_alloc` exception when it can't properly create the requested object, even though the stuff said before suggests that it might not be possible. But any implementation **must** make sure it works, in whatever way.